# How to tell if a translation unit is being compiled with segmented stacks

Tags: c++, portability

Is there a preprocessor macro, constant or something similar in C++ that can be used to tell if a translation unit is being compiled with segmented stacks (i.e. with `-fsplit-stack`)?

Answers for any compiler would be good but I am looking for clang and gcc in particular

Comment: `objdump -h ./myobjfile.o | grep split-stack`

Comment: @HadiBrais I need a way to determine this programmatically so it can be used in c++ to conditionally compile parts of the code. So I don't think this approach will work, unless you know of some magic introspection technique here :)

Comment: Your question says you want to know how tell if a translation unit **was compiled**. You should changed that to **being compiled**.

Comment: @HadiBrais done, edited the question

Answer (score 2):

According to [this gcc wiki page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks#Implementation_steps:), the preprocessor gets `TARGET_SUPPORTS_SPLIT_STACK` and the runtime gets `bool supports_split_stack()`.

Comment: Thanks!  Isn't that just saying that a compiler that can support split stacks will have to define that function?  Not that if segmented stacks are supported that function will be defined and will return true?

Comment: @Curious I'm not certain, sorry.

Comment: Is there a general convention for such flags?  For example can someone tell if a program has been compiled with `-fno-rtti`?

Comment: @Curious Right. `TARGET_SUPPORTS_SPLIT_STACK` only tells whether target architecture supports split stacks or not. It doesn't tell you whether the translation unit is being compiled with `-fsplit-stack`. There is no macro for that I think.

Comment: For RTTI, some compilers supports [some magic](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checks-for-standard-language-features) that is applicable for a translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, inspecting gcc source code from the master branch of [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc) says that no visible side effects come from `flag_split_stack` other than in codegen and link level which might be too late. I've not looked upon clang code as deeply as gcc but probably the situation should be similar.

If you could permit runtime inspections as well, you might be able to write a platform-specific detection for each of them (e.g., [`__morestack()` call](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+main()%7B%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-fsplit-stack',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) detection by inspecting code; refer to `morestack.S`), but it should be somewhat in similar situation to objdump usage in the sense that it cannot be leveraged in compile-time diagnostics.

Probaby the best way is to request a feature to the compiler vendors, or to add a custom macro using `-D` with `-fsplit-stack` itself if you have control over the build system.